# Create Remote Desktop with WebRTC

Tags: node.js, webrtc

is possible create a remote desktop app between browsers with WebRTC (or maybe with Node.JS if possible)?

I see the Google Chrome have this extension, but i need create a remote desktop app to my helpdesk software.

Comment: You may be interested in `guacamole` - a HTML5 client-less remote desktop. It's open source with MIT license. Ref: http://guac-dev.org/

Comment: Yes it is possible to create remote desktop using WebRTC. Please checkout this project:
https://github.com/imtiyazs/webrtc-remote-desktop

Comment: @ImtiyazShaikh i need your help please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try chrome's [desktopCapture](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture.html) experimental extension API. You can test [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webrtc-desktop-sharing/nkemblooioekjnpfekmjhpgkackcajhg)!

### Updated at: Oct 06, 2015

[desktopCapture API](https://github.com/muaz-khan/Chrome-Extensions) in Chrome or [screen capturing API](https://github.com/muaz-khan/Firefox-Extensions) in Firefox doesn't provides remote-desktop-access or remote-desktop-control.

Both API providers generates stateless screen; and remote users can merely view the screen.

**Here is a browser-based VNC client:**

> VNC client using HTML5 (Web Sockets, Canvas) with encryption (wss://) support. http://novnc.com
>
> Source code: https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC

You can easily switch from WebSockets to WebRTC data channels.

Comment: May be you can try this implementation of WebRTC Remote Desktop.

https://github.com/imtiyazs/webrtc-remote-desktop

Comment: @ImtiyazShaikh your link is broken, can you fix it?

Comment: I wish I could. The project is bought by a company so had to remove it.

Answer (score 12):

Try this: VNC client on [200 lines of JavaScript](http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/08/30/vnc-javascript-nodejs/)

[Guacamole is a](http://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/) clientless remote desktop gateway. It supports standard protocols like VNC and RDP.
Thanks to HTML5, once Guacamole server is installed, all you need to access your desktops is a web browser.

Answer (score 5):

[ScreenCat](https://github.com/maxogden/screencat) is a remote desktop in JS using WebRTC under the hood.

Comment: only for MacOS, and the project was abandoned :(